# c# reflection (or another way to get class values via injected dll)

Tags: c#, dll, code-injection

I've been searching the web for the past 3 weeks trying to get this to work and I'm not having any luck.

A little back story: Injecting a C# .NET 4.0 DLL into a .NET 4.0 application.

(I can get my DLL injected using a bootstrap DLL written in C++ and can call functions in the application)

I can get this code to work but what I am trying to do is get the "actual" values instead of creating a new instance of the class.

Below is a working example of the Reflection working the way I don't want it to work and I'm not sure if reflection is even what I need to be using at this point. Or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

```
namespace TestFormsApp4
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static TestClass1 Test = new TestClass1("from class 1");
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            BindingFlags Binding = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
            Assembly App = Assembly.Load("TestFormsApp4");
            //Get the TestFormsApp4.Program (static) type
            Type Test1C = App.GetType("TestFormsApp4.Program");
            //get the testclass2 field (TestClass2 testclass2;)
            var Test1F = Test1C.GetField("Test", Binding);
            //get the value from the field
            var Test2C = Test1F.GetValue(Test1C);

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

namespace TestName1
{                      
    class TestClass1
    {
        public bool testbool = false;
        public TestClass2 testclass2;
        public TestClass1(String SetString)
        {
            this.testclass2 = new TestClass2(SetString);
        }
    }
}

namespace TestName2
{
    class TestClass2
    {
        public String teststring;
        public TestClass2(String SetString)
        {
            teststring = SetString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *the "actual" values* mean? do you mean there is an existing instance somewhere? if so: where is that instance? you can't get the values without knowing the reference (although it is fine if you only know it as `object`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that code cannot work.  You must obtain a reference to the existing instance of the class you are interested in.  Creating a new instance doesn't buy you anything but the properties you set on such an instance yourself.  Such a reference can be quite difficult to obtain, there is no way to iterate the objects on the garbage collected heap.

Necessarily you need a *static* variable in the program that tracks the created instances.  There's one hint that such a variable may exist, it looks like you are doing something with forms.  The Application.OpenForms is a static variable that references a collection of the opened forms.  You can iterate it and use GetType() to find an instance of a specific form type.  As long as that form object stores a reference to the "TestClass" instance then you can dig it out with Reflection.  Also the way that the ManagedSpy++ tool works.

Comment: This actually makes total sense now that I think about it. As long as the values I'm looking for are declared as static somewhere. I've edited my original post to reflect what the code would have to look like (using reflection) to find the value of this static class. Now the question is, is this a new instance of my application or the one that exists in memory?